# Renders fine, but, Render Preview works - (Pink) Material Preview doesn't (Cycles - 3.0, 3.1, 3.2b)

Tags: 3d-view

This is what I see:

(Procedural or Textured Shader - Makes no difference)

[image]

Additional Error Message (Unrelated to Shader)

[image: Error Message]

Checked "External Data".  Even created dummy images based on error messages.  Error messages went away.  Problem remained.

Cleaned Up (File Clean Up) - everything.  Didn't help.

Basic PBR Shader works.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i turned on and off that option and it started working fine , im on 3.2.1